# Error in R : search_tweets()` was deprecated in rtweet 2.0.0 and is now defunct

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

Error: The removal of API v1.1 made this function obsolete.

Note: I am looking for some tweets having a set of terms (Eg: "stock price of Tesla") using the search_tweets(). I also tried similar functions like search_30day(), search_tweets2(),etc all show the same error. I have checked the version of Rstudio and Rtools that I am using, they match.

I am unable to resolve this error when I try to search for tweets using "rtweets" package.

Comment: Space Karen threw a tantrum and broke Twitter. It no longer has an API. Or a name. You can no longer search its content. This has nothing to do with this particular package.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/761#issuecomment-1688378596

Comment: Twitter has blocked its former API, which granted everybody access to its publicly available data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the maintainer of the rtweet pacakge: I added that error deep inside the rtweet code to prevent calling functions that shouldn't work (that's why it appears in many functions and it is not easy to avoid it).

Apparently for some users the API v1.1 still work, so now it is a warning. You can install the devel version on github via `remotes::install_github("ropensci/rtweet")`, but these functions might still fail.
The recommended way is to use the new endpoints (which rtweet provides some functions), but it has some non-negligible subscription cost...